# List all Array.prototype functions in IE8-

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, internet-explorer-8, prototype

Is it possible to loop through all JavaScript `Array.prototype` function names in a cross-browser friendly way? I know this works in IE9+ and modern browsers:

```
var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype);
names.forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name); // function name
});
```

Is there a way to get the same list in IE8 & IE7? I tried:

```
for(var key in Array.prototype) {
    console.log(key); // undefined
}
```

Comment: If you're talking about the native, non-enumerable properties, then no there's not. At least not without manually making an enumerable list, or perhaps finding some hackish `toString()` trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find what is supported in an IE browser before version 9, you can assume that it is a subset of IE9's list and  winnow out the ones not supported.

This is the list you get in IE before #9:

**concat, constructor, join, length, pop, push, reverse, shift, slice, sort, splice, toLocaleString, toString, unshift**

You can test it-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Small Page</title>
<style>
</style>
<script>
onload= function(){
var testnames= ['concat', 'constructor', 'every', 'filter', 'forEach',
'indexOf', 'join', 'lastIndexOf', 'length', 'map', 'pop', 'push', 'reduce',
'reduceRight', 'reverse', 'shift', 'slice', 'some', 'sort', 'splice',
'toLocaleString', 'toString', 'unshift'],
    L= 23;
    while(L){
        if(!(testnames[--L]in Array.prototype)) testnames.splice(L, 1);
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value= testnames;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<p>   <textarea rows="8" cols="60"> </textarea>     </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ironically, jsfiddle doesn't seem to support IE8. Hahaha.